# Combining vertically adjacent Areas does not reduce segments in Java

Tags: java, geometry, area

How do I combine two `java.awt.geom.Area`s to reduce the number of segments/vertices?

It works as expected for horizontally adjacent `Area`s, but not vertically (see image and code output).

[image: vertical and horizontal area combining]

```java
Area area1 = new Area(); // Test combining vertically
Area area2 = new Area(); // Test combining horizontally

area1.add(new Area(new Polygon(
    new int[] { 0, 0, 64, 64 }, // x-coords
    new int[] { 0, 64, 64, 0 }, // y-coords
    4)));                       // #-points
area1.add(new Area(new Polygon(
    new int[] { 0, 0, 64, 64 },
    new int[] { 64, 128, 128, 64 },
    4)));

area2.add(new Area(new Polygon(
    new int[] { 0, 0, 64, 64 },
    new int[] { 0, 64, 64, 0 },
    4)));
area2.add(new Area(new Polygon(
    new int[] { 64, 64, 128, 128 },
    new int[] { 0, 64, 64, 0 },
    4)));
```

which gives the following output when traversing the `PathIterator` segments (see image too):

```
// area1
move to: (0, 0)
line to: (0, 64)  // Unnecessary
line to: (0, 128)
line to: (64, 128)
line to: (64, 64) // Unnecessary
line to: (64, 0)
// area2
move to: (0, 0)
line to: (0, 64)
line to: (128, 64)
line to: (128, 0)
```

Comment: @Gene Do you happen to know why it works horizontally though?

Comment: Sorry I was wrong. Here's the source code for `Area`. https://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/awt/geom/Area-source.html  It does implement polygon union, intersection, and subtraction.  It only guarantees the result has the correct boundary.  So as far as it's concerned, what you see is not an error.  You could trace your case in the code to see what it's doing.

Comment: The docs say "An Area may take more path segments to describe the same geometry even when the original outline is simple and obvious. The analysis that the Area class must perform on the path may not reflect the same concepts of "simple and obvious" as a human being perceives."